# How to include common elements in onsen ui pages?

Tags: onsen-ui2

Is there a way to include commmon elements e.g splitter menu in different html pages in onsen ui rather than repeating the code on each page?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was kinda vague, but if I understand correctly you want the ons-splitter to persist across multiple pages? If that's the case, you should just be updating the ons-splitter-content inside ons-splitter, it can be any valid html.

Same thing goes for ons-tabbar for example, change the "content" element, and the tab structure will persist across pages.

Here's an example in the documentation for multiple pages with a splitter:

https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-splitter.html